# Set selected value of dropdowns from cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have three dropdowns in my form, and I would like to not lose the data that the user has selected, even if I refresh or I navigate in other page and come back.

This is my view where I have the 3 dropdowns:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchForCars", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "DivCategoriesTree", OnSuccess = "success", HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { make = "makes" }))
            {
                <div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 10em;display: flex;align-items: center ; padding-top:25px;">
                        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red; padding-left:20px;"></i>
                        <strong style="padding-left:20px;">Vă rugăm să selectați vehiculul dumneavoastră!</strong>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div style="padding-top:15px;">
                            <form class="form-control-static">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                      <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            @if (ViewData.ContainsKey("makes"))
                                            {
                                                @Html.DropDownList("makes", ViewData["makes"] as List<SelectListItem>, "--Select car--", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle form-control" })
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <p></p>
                                            @Html.DropDownList("models", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select model--", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle form-control" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <p></p>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            @Html.DropDownList("engines", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select engine--", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle form-control" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 10em;display: flex;align-items: center ; padding-top:25px;">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-default active" value="Cauta" disabled="disabled" style="width:150px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

Here are the 3 dropdowns:

[image]

I use cookies to store the data that the user has selected.

I tried to set the dropdown from the controller in this way:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var asa = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("make_model_engine");
        var model = asa.Values["model"].ToString();
        var make = asa.Values["make"].ToString();

        var makeList = new SelectList(makeRepository.GetMakes(), "ID", "Name");
        ViewData["makes"] = makeList;

        **var selected = makeList.Where(x => x.Value == make).First();
        selected.Selected = true;**
        return View();

    }
```

Although it seems that the selected value is set correctly from cookies, it does not work, the dropdowns are not showing the selected value.
I guess that I should fix this in the view with javascript, but I'm new to javascript and I don't know what would be the best fix for this. 
Can you please help me how can I resolve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the selected value you read from the cookie as the last parameter of the [`SelectList` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.#ctor(System.Collections.IEnumerable,System.String,System.String,System.Object)):

```
var makeList = new SelectList(makeRepository.GetMakes(), "ID", "Name", make);
```

Comment: This is working for the first dropdown, thanks!  but for second and third dropdown I need another fix, because they are build from jquery in the view. I can not reach them from controller.

Comment: If they are built with jquery, you will need to set the selected value with javascript.

Comment: Yes, but I'm quite new the javascript and I don't know how would be the best way to do that in  js.

Comment: Well, in this case maybe you could go through some tutorials in order to get started.